# Conceder permissão a um novo usuário no SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissões

Estou tentando atribuir permissões de `db_datawriter` e `db_datareader` a um usuário novo no SQL Manager

Os seguintes passos foram executados:

```
-- criação do usuário
CREATE LOGIN apostila   WITH PASSWORD = 'qweQWE123!@#';

-- usuário como dbcreator
ALTER SERVER ROLE  dbcreator  ADD MEMBER apostila;
```

Agora estou tentando atribuir `db_datareader` e `db_datawriter` para o usuário `apostila`. Tentei das seguintes formas e nenhuma funcionou:

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'apostila'

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [apostila]
```

Ao fazer isso recebo o seguinte erro:

> Cannot add the principal 'apostila', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Isso por que de alguma forma, o DB não está entendendo que o usuário `apostila` existe.

Se eu logar como `apostila` e buscar `CURRENT_USER` ele vai retornar `guest`. Isso implica que se eu colocar `guest` na `sp_addrolemember`, ai ele aceita e atribuiu `db_datareader` a todos os guests da aplicação, e este é o ponto.

**Como atribuir `db_datareader` apenas para um usuário e não todos os guests?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É preciso criar um usuário para dar permissão de db_datareader.
Isso porque o login é referente ao acesso na instância SQL.
Usuários é no nível de objetos do banco. E como leitura é referente ao banco, é necessário criar um usuário.

```
CREATE USER NomeUsuario FOR LOGIN apostila   

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER apostila
```